# CSS doesn't load in my webapp

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I have an hybrid webapp and, at a given moment, I want to display my webpage in it. I obtain my page's HTML with an AJAX call and everything works fine in preview mode. However, when I run my app on Android (cordova webview, no crosswalk), it seems that the css files inside my HTML's head don't load. My webpage is displayed without any css settings. Is there any reason that explains why it works while previewing but not in Android? Why does it load the HTML code but not the CSS files?

Comment: Can you add some code

Comment: android `www` code is located under `assets` folder. please check there what do you see in `index.html`

Comment: @NitishPhanse what code do you need?

Comment: @MaximShoustin my index.html was created with Construct 2 (game maker engine), it is simply a canvas that draws the app every frame.

Comment: We need the code that is causing the problem. We are not mind readers - cannot help if we can't see where the problem is! Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FluffyKitten thank you for your advice, but I don't really know which code is causing the problem. I get the page's html via AJAX (there is no problem) and it is displayed inside a div, nothing else. I am hintless because it works perfectly in Preview Mode, so I was thinking more of something like a permission problem in Android or anything like that rather than a problem in my code.

Comment: Its very difficult for us to help when we cannot see your set up or code, so I'm not sure what we can do for you in that case.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Sorry, you are right. The truth is I am really a noob, I am not even a coder, I use Construct 2 which is an engine designed for non-coders haha. Anyway, it's solved. The problem was that the links in my webpage were given like href="//www.domain.com/subfolder/file.css" and for some reason I had to replace "//" with "http://". Thank you for your help and sorry for my dumbness.